# Printfing a FPU register value

Tags: assembly, floating-point, fpu

I want to somehow get the value from FPU register and printf it. I've got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void change();
void single_precision();

int main()
{
    float a = 3.14;
    printf("%f", a);
}
```

`gcc -S` generates this:

```
    .file   "zad4.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC1:
    .string "%f"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $20, %esp
    flds    .LC0
    fstps   -12(%ebp)
    flds    -12(%ebp)
    subl    $4, %esp
    leal    -8(%esp), %esp
    fstpl   (%esp)
    pushl   $.LC1
    call    printf
    addl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx
    leave
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 4
.LC0:
    .long   1078523331
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.3.1 20170306"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Apart from some mess on the beginning of main, it basically loads the value (this `.long`, it could be hardcoded as `.float 3.14`, whatever) to FPU register. Then it takes that value to the `-12(%ebp)`, loads it again. But I don't know what happens next

Why does it `leal -8(%esp), %esp`? Then it pops the value again from FPU register to `(%esp)`, so that would be the address of `-8(%esp)`. Then it prinfts.

And now, if I would like to see every little bit of this number, using for example `bt` instruction, then where should I store it? I guess I cannot `movl` it, cuz its 80-bit long

```
Generated with `-O3`:

    .file   "XD.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC1:
    .string "%f"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $8, %esp
    pushl   $1074339512
    pushl   $1610612736
    pushl   $.LC1
    call    printf
    movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx
    addl    $16, %esp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.3.1 20170306"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Try compiling the code with the `-O3` (optimization level 3) option to remove a lot of extra loads and stores. Might make the code easier to understand. Alot of that startup code aligns the stack to a 16 byte boundary and at the end restores the stack to the way it was.

Comment: With `-O3` it just simply pushes the value of this `.long` to the stack (not FPU stack) and `printf`s it

Comment: Yep, without optimizations the code generation does extra (unnecessary) loads and stores to memory. The `-O3` output is much cleaner. It is at least easier to read and understand.

Comment: With the `-O3` output anything upto the `push %ecx` exists to align the stack to a 16-bye boundary (per the i386 Linux ABI) Everything from `movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx` to the bottom restores the stack to its original state and then returns.

Comment: Variadic functions (like printf) require promoting 32-bit floats to 64-bit double floats. The two pushes (`pushl   $1074339512`
    `pushl   $1610612736`) are the 64-bit representation of the 32-bit float 3.14.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But how can I printf the value, which I first put into FPU registers? And how to print in in binary

Comment: You can use the `fst` instruction to take a value from the top of the FPU stack and store it to memory. FST can store the 80-bit value on the FPU stack to a 32-bit, 64-bit, or 80-bit value at the specified memory location. `fstp` puts the value on the top of FPU stack into memory and then automatically pops that value off the FPU stack. `fst` simply stores the value to memory. I edited this comment. My first version said `fld` when it should have been `fst` (or `fstp`)

Comment: But `store it to memory` means store it on the stack, or store it where?

Comment: Store it to memory address. Create a label with enough size to receive the value. A memory address can also point to the stack too (which would be preferred)

Comment: If you are taking a class then have you considered talking to your professor or teacher assistant?

Comment: Yeah, but then I would prolly receive some bad grade as it is a homework

Comment: Does this have to be 32bits? Intel 32bit uses x87 which is a somewhat archaic stack based architecture. 64bit uses SIMD which can be faster and is at least a lot easier to read.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Note that you can use both the x87 and MMX floating point units in both modes. And you could just look at OPs code to find out what FPU he uses. The x87 is not archaic by any mean either.

Comment: I realize that you can mix x87 in 64bit and SIMD in 32 bit but I was keeping it simple and referring to the defaults with just -m32/-m64. As for the x87, it might have been groundbreaking back in the early 80s but I don't see any current FPUs using a stack architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which prints out the value in `st0` using `printf`, I hope this is what you need:

```
    .data
.fmtstr:
    .string "%f\n"


    .text
    # print floating point value in st0
print_float:
    sub $8,%esp  # make space on the stack
    fstp (%esp)  # store the value we want to print
    push $fmtstr # push formatting string
    call printf
    add $12,%esp # pop arguments back off
    ret
```

Note that we need to use `fstp` as the C calling convention requires that the 8087 stack is empty on function call.

You can also print the whole 80 bits of a floating point number using the `%Lf` formatting specifier:

```
    .data
.fmtstr:
    .string "%Lf\n"


    .text
    # print floating point value in st0
print_float:
    sub $12,%esp # make space on the stack
    fstpt (%esp) # store the value we want to print
    push $fmtstr # push formatting string
    call printf
    add $16,%esp # pop arguments back off
    ret
```

Note that we make space for 12 bytes instead of 10. This is because 2 bytes of padding are needed to align the 10 byte argument to 12 bytes.

If you want to see the bytes of the floating point number, you can just pretend that the 10 bytes you pushed are actually two ints and a short:

```
    .data
.fmtstr:
    .string "%02x%04x%04x\n"

    .text
    # print st0 in hex
print_float:
    pushw $0     # pad with explicit zeros
    sub $10,%esp # make space for the number
    fstpt (%esp) # store the value we want to print
    push $fmtstr # push formatting string
    call printf
    add $16,%esp # pop arguments back off
    ret
```

Comment: The `%LF` specifier that u pointed just prints f.e `3.140000`

Comment: @Frynio What did you want instead?

Comment: Something like `1001001010101...` etc.

Comment: @Frynio Well, the last one prints the number in hexadecimal. There is no `printf` modifier to print in binary, but if you like I can write a procedure for you that does so.